# Camunda BPM PLATFORM SETUP

Tags: camunda, business-process-management

Thanks in advance. I am trying to build Camunda platoform from the following Git repo.

https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform

Can anyone please guide me on how to set up this project and execute it step by step.

regards
-Manash

How to set-up and execute Camunda code base.

Comment: ...but why build all yourself? And what have you tried that did not work. Please add detail to your question.

Comment: docker pull camunda/camunda-bpm-platform:run-latest
docker run -d --name camunda -p 8080:8080 camunda/camunda-bpm-platform:run-latest

Answer (score 1):

There are many easier ways to setup Camunda 7 than building it yourself. Even when making modification, there usually are SPIs/extension points you can work with.

If you are a Spring Boot developer, you may prefer the [Camunda Spring boot initalizer](https://start.camunda.com/). However, this may lead to an embedded engine architecture, which you may want to avoid in the light of Camunda 8.

If you want an external engine or don't work with Java you can use a [container image](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.18/installation/docker/) or download the [RUN distribution](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.18/installation/camunda-bpm-run/). You can the use the external task worker pattern to integrate services.

If you want to explore Camunda 8, then it is easiest to use the try for free button on https://camunda.com/ and let yourself be guided by the tutorial.

If you want to use Camunda 8, but don't want to use Saas, you can go for a [self-managed installation](https://docs.camunda.io/docs/self-managed/about-self-managed/).

And, of course, there are the "Getting started" guides for Camunda

- Camunda 7 https://docs.camunda.org/get-started/
- Camunda 8 https://docs.camunda.io/docs/guides/

Answer (score 0):

As Rob suggested, you must use official distros. But if you still want to do this for some reason like bumping up the dependencies.
Steps are as follows for Camunda 7.18.0 :

1. Install Jdk 15 on your machine (JDK17 will also work)
2. Checkout the code, You must checkout 7.18.0 Tag
3. Modify the parent/pom.xml file and add following repository under **repositories** section.

> ```
> <repository>
>   <id>camunda-bpm-nexus</id>
>   <name>Camunda Platform Maven Repository</name>
>   <url>https://artifacts.camunda.com/artifactory/public/</url>
> </repository>
> ```

4. Decide which version of Camunda Distro you wish to Build Let's say you want to build Camunda Run and fire the command in Powershell/Gitbash

> ./mvnw clean package -P distro-run

There are multiple Profiles, based on need you must modify the above command.

- distro-tomcat
- distro-wildfly
- distro-webjar
- distro-ce
- distro-run